# Gap between <div>

Tags: php, html, css

I tried searching and using the codes I found somewhere else where it suggests to put:

> margin:0px;

, but it still doesn't resolve my issue about the GAP created between the **divs** of my file. Here's the code: [The first one's the Jquery, the second is for the CSS, and the last one is the body.]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var navOffset = jQuery(".nav").offset().top;

 jQuery(".nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
 jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery(".nav").outerHeight());

 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

  var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  if(scrollPos >= navOffset){
   jQuery(".nav").addClass("fixed");
  }
  else{
   jQuery(".nav").removeClass("fixed");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body, html {
                height: 100%;
                background-color:#404040;
                margin:0px;
        }
        .parallax {
            background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
            height: 100%;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            font-size:0;
            margin-bottom:0px;
        }
        .parallax1 {
            background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
            height: 46%;
            font-size:0;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        ul.header{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width:100%;
            top:0;            
            display: inline-block;
            text-align:center;
            background-color: #0d0d0d;
        }
        .nav{
            z-index:999;
        }
        .navlink {
            display: inline-block
        }
        .fixed{
            position: fixed;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#222422;
        }
        .nav-placeholder{
            margin:0 0 40px 0;
        }
        .navlink a{
            font-family: caviar;
            display: block;
            color: #f3f3f3;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:15pt;
        }
        .navlink a:hover{
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            color:#0d0d0d;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
        }
        .caption {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 50%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
        }
        .caption span.border {
            background-color: #111;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 18px;
            font-size: 25px;
            letter-spacing: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>
<div class="caption">
    <span class="border"> WELCOME </span>
</div>
<div class="nav">
        <ul class="header">
            <ul class="header-content">
                <li class="navlink"><a href="{{ route('beverage_main') }}">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="{{ route('beverage_foods') }}"> Foods </a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#"> Beverages </a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</div>

  <!-- Here's where the gap appears -->
  
<div id="content" style="height:300px;background-color:#f2f2f2;font-size:36px;text-align:center;">
<p>Sample Facebook Icon</p>
</div>


<div class="parallax1"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/js.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What gap are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of reasons:

1. `p` element has margins.
2. `.nav-placeholder` class has `margin-bottom: 40px;`
3. `ul.header` (which should be `div.header`) is displayed as
   inline-block and pushes its parent height - leave its default
   display as block.

Comment: I resolved this issue by setting the margin-bottom of .nav-placeholder to 0px. Thank you so much :) Now, how do I close this as solved?

Comment: Thank you so much, again. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to the gap between your nav links, it is because `display: inline-block;` creates a gap by inserting a space between the elements. One solution to fix this is to set the parent container `font-size: 0;`.

```
.nav{
   font-size: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unueg9zL/

Comment: I tried this earlier but it didn't work. The gap still appears between the Navigation bar and the content (which is "Sample facebook icon"). The issue was resolved, tho. I just removed the margin-bottom of the .nav-paceholder to 0px. Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` you are adding inside `#content` is adding the gap, `p` elements have a default `margin=1em` (added by the browsers). You should set that `margin` to `0px` explicitly on your CSS rules

```
#content p {margin:0}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hkuo8xdx/

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this, but I resolved the issue by setting the margin-bottom from 40px to 0px. :) Thank you, anyways.